# Using sed to compact JSON arrays

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sed, awk, json

I have a JSON output in the following format:

```
{
  "DaysCfg": {
    "Range": {
      "lowerDate": "2017-07-28T00:00:00.000-04:00",
      "upperDate": "2017-08-04T00:00:00.000-04:00"
    },
    "DaysInPeriod": 8,
    "DaysToSchedule": [
      0,
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5,
      6
    ]
  },
  "DepartmentsID": [
    138837,
    139734,
    141934,
    142436,
    149687,
    151049
  ],
  "EmployeesID": [
    5039,
    5170,
    5889,
    6051,
    6236,
    7208,
    7281,
    8776,
    8781,
    8936,
    9261
  ],
  "EndDate": "2017-08-03T23:59:00.000-04:00",
  "IntervalSize": 15,
  "IsActivitiesEnabled": true,
  "ModifyExisting": false,
  "OrignId": 134721,
  "PrimaryOption": 0,
  "SchoolDays": [],
  "ScChanges": [],
  "StartDate": "2017-07-28T00:00:00.000-04:00",
  "ZonesToSchedule": [
    5,
    4,
    6,
    3,
    3,
    3,
    2,
    14
  ]
}
```

Since I can't change the program that output it, I have to use `sed` (or `awk`) to compact JSON arrays myself. The desirable output would be:

```
{
  "DaysCfg": {
    "Range": {
      "lowerDate": "2017-07-28T00:00:00.000-04:00",
      "upperDate": "2017-08-04T00:00:00.000-04:00"
    },
    "DaysInPeriod": 8,
    "DaysToSchedule": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  },
  "DepartmentsID": [138837, 139734, 141934, 142436, 149687, 151049],
  "EmployeesID": [5039, 5170, 5889, 6051, 6236, 7208, 7281, 8776, 8781, 8936, 9261],
  "EndDate": "2017-08-03T23:59:00.000-04:00",
  "IntervalSize": 15,
  "IsActivitiesEnabled": true,
  "ModifyExisting": false,
  "OrignId": 134721,
  "PrimaryOption": 0,
  "SchoolDays": [],
  "ScChanges": [],
  "StartDate": "2017-07-28T00:00:00.000-04:00",
  "ZonesToSchedule": [5, 4, 6, 3, 3, 3, 2, 14]
}
```

I have tried to come up a `sed` script myself, but it is only half-cooked and not fully working:

```
sed -r -e :a -e '/^ *[]}],*$/!N; /": \[/s/\n +//; ta' -e 'P;D'
```

Please Help. Thx.

Comment: I think `sed` isn't the best tool for this problem. You should try some JSON-parser/formatter, for example `jq` (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). Maybe you want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105031/how-to-beautify-json-in-python-or-through-command-line and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-in-unix-shell-script

Comment: FYI, the output that I wanted to work on, is created exactly by `jq`, a `C` program, thus I'm not interested in any Python solutions. @uzsolt. What you see here is only a selected representation of of 4~6M output that I'm having. If you don't understand the above `sed` command, then it is inappropriate for you to make the judgment whether `sed` is the best tool or not.

Comment: So, what do you want exactly? You want delete '\n' (after a comma) *if* we  are inside brackets (`[` and `]`). If you want do it with `sed` just do it! It isn't impossible but "FYI" there are better tools. I'm curious about the `sed`-way solution. Go for it! (Someone downvoted your question - FYI not me)

Comment: Thanks for the input @uzsolt. OK, I gotya. I'll forget about `sed` and do it in `awk` then.

Comment: The down-voting shows nothing but there are narrow minded and mean people out in the wild. I'll do it in `awk` and post back.

Comment: I think `awk` is better *in this case* :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I edited your sed, hope this helps.

```
sed -r '/\[$/ {:a;N;s/\]/&/;Ta;s/\n +//g}'

sed -r '

# sed will apply the commands between '{}' only to lines that matches the address '/\[$/'.
/\[$/ {

# Set a mark with label 'a'.
:a

# N command, it appends a '\n' to the pattern space,
# reads the next line of the input (file,stdin) and appends it to the pattern space.
N

# Substitute ']' for itself. If the substitution isn't made (if there isn't a ']' on the
# pattern space), the 'T' command jumps to the 'a' label.
# Here is the loop to put some lines (or all lines of a file) in the same line.
# While there isn't a ']' in the pattern space (which is the last line OP wants to put
# on the same line), sed will append '\n<next line>' to the pattern space.
s/\]/&/
Ta

# When the substitution is made, sed leaves the loop and applies other commands.
# Substitute all occurrences (g flag) of new line character (with any
# spaces after) for nothing.
s/\n +//g
}'
```

Comment: OMG! That's amazing. I've been dissuaded by people to have given up on `sed`, but deep down in my mind I still believe `sed` can do it, and ... BANG!  here is your unbelievable simple solution, which works flawlessly!!! Please take my +50 points in total as a warm welcome to superuser!

Comment: I think I understand almost everything, but how the loops terminates. Would you elaborate please?

Comment: Now I wish I've had more down-votes for this question -- obviously they down-voted because they don't believe there will be a `sed` solution, _even in their wildest imaginations_. To all those people, this excellent answer shows how narrow minded you are in your face.

Comment: I can only award my +50 bounty in 23 hours, so take my +25 points for now.

Comment: I figured it out myself from the man `T label`: "_If  no  `s///`  has  done a successful substitution since the last
              input line was read and since the last  `t`  or  `T`  command,  then
              branch  to  label_"

Comment: Excuse me I don't know much how the "points stuff" works but thank you very much for the points.Finally I have enough points to comment :) thanks. Yes you're right, the 'T' command does the job for jumping to the 'a' label if there isn't any ']' in the pattern space. All the commands are applied only when sed finds a line with the address '/\[$/' , other lines are printed without any edition.

Comment: Nice answer, but I suggest you add an explanation section with a breakdown of the command in order to illustrate how it works. It appears you are using some `sed` functionality that not everybody is familiar with.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: Edited to add explanation. See 'info sed' for GNU-sed commands. ps- excuse me for English errors.